# Axios Network Error in React Native with Expo in Android

Tags: android, react-native, http, axios, expo

I'm trying to run an API call in React Native on Android with Expo using Axios, but I'm encountering a network error. I tried some solutions, but nothing seems to work. This is the error displayed in the console:

```
Network Error
at node_modules\\axios\\lib\\core\\AxiosError.js:3:0in \<global\>
at node_modules\\axios\\lib\\adapters\\xhr.js:138:8 in handleAbort
at node_modules\\event-target-shim\\dist\\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
at node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\Network\\XMLHttpRequest.js:647:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\Network\\XMLHttpRequest.js:396:6 in didCompleteResponse
at node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\vendor\\emitter_EventEmitter.js:150:10 in EventEmitter#emit
at node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\BatchedBridge\\MessageQueue.js:417:4 in callFunction
at node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\BatchedBridge\\MessageQueue.js:114:6 in guard$argument_0
at node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\BatchedBridge\\MessageQueue.js:368:10 in guard
at node_modules\\react-native\\Libraries\\BatchedBridge\\MessageQueue.js:113:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I tried changing the localhost in the API link to my IP address, as well as to 10.0.2.2, but nothing worked. I checked my internet permission in AndroidManifest and made some other permission changes to the file, but nothing seemed to resolve it. I hope to find a solution to the problem soon.

Comment: This stack trace doesn't have much info, can you build from Android Studio or use something like Reactotron to get more info?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a tool like expo go, [`axiosError: Network error`] is simply an error saying that the api you provided may not be reached.
so if you want to pull data from a local storage instead of cloud storage ... you may create a server like for example `php artisan serve` then create an Ngrok server for that server , afterwards take the link you received from the ngrok then use it as your new API endpoint

Answer (score -1):

i m the same problem. you found solution l